# Error when creating an excel workbook on desktop using C#

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I want to create an excel workbook on my desktop using C#. My code looks like:

```
string exportLocation = "C:/Users/yqin/Desktop/Enrollment.xlsx";
Excel.Workbook workbook = Ex.Workbooks.Add(exportLocation);
Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add();
```

However when I ran the code it gave me an error:
Sorry, we couldn't find C:\Users\yqin\Desktop\Enrollment.xlsx. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?

I thought I have used add to create a new excel file rather than using existing ones. Why do I get this error? Thanks for the help!

Comment: See if the path leading up to the file exists.

Comment: The actual file path looks like this: C:\Users\yqin\Desktop, however when I copy this into Visual Studio it says "Unrecognized escape sequence"

Comment: Put an `@` before path, so `string exportLocation = @"C:\Users\yqin\Desktop\Enrollment.xlsx";`. Slashes are escape characters and the `@` automatically escapes them for you.

Comment: @Equalsk, works beautifully! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path should contain backslashes (`\`), not forward slashes. Microsoft has advocated for the use of \ as the path separator for decades.

Also, use an `@` at the beginning to avoid having to escape all the escape characters such as backslash.

```
string exportLocation = @"C:\Users\yqin\Desktop\Enrollment.xlsx";
```

This (`@""`) creates a verbatim string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim